# Data encrypted by LOCKY virus

Tags: malware, trojan

Is there any way to decrypt the data which is affected and encrypted by locky ransomeware hackers. one of our companies system (windows 7) is affected. i have Ubuntu installed on my PC. please help anyone , if there is any war for the recovery.

Thanks.

Comment: Restore it from a back up...

Answer (score 0):

Restore your PC to a previous version using System Restore

Or have a go at Kaspersky's (Kasperskies?!) decrypt tool, I have seen success with this on various cryptolockers (not sure about LOCKY though).

https://noransom.kaspersky.com

Might as well give it a blast, eh?

Comment: This doesn't appear to decrypt user files, if I read the link correctly.

Comment: "Kaspersky WindowsUnlocker does not perform any actions with files (in order to disinfect files you can use Kaspersky Rescue Disk).". How does this tool help the author beyond clearing out the malware which is the least of their problems ( it also wasn't the problem they are looking to solve )

Comment: WindowsUnlocker is a different thing from Kaspersky Decryptor. https://noransom.kaspersky.com

Comment: @Overmind Oh yeah my bad sorry. Was just a quick answer. I edited it.

Answer (score -1):

Most ransomware encryption systems disable restore capabilities, including VS, System Restore.

A chance to recover your files is the determine exactly what version of encryption   ransomware it is and see if theres a program written to decrypt it. Some ransomware encryption is supported even by large AV companies like Kaspersky Lab [Decryptors](https://noransom.kaspersky.com).

Some of them though, were not reversible and therefore you will not be able to decrypt the files encrypted by them.